# MongoDB update array object filed with value of another field of that same object array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like the following:

```
{
    _id: asilu92834,
    services: [
        {
            chargeAmount: 10,
            calculatedChargeAmount: 5,
        },
        {
            chargeAmount: 20,
            calculatedChargeAmount: 15,
        }
    ]
}
```

what I am trying to do is to update the chargeAmount field with it's object's value of calculatedChargeAmount field. After the update the doc should look like the following:

```
{
    _id: asilu92834,
    services: [
        {
            chargeAmount: 5,
            calculatedChargeAmount: 5,
        },
        {
            chargeAmount: 15,
            calculatedChargeAmount: 15,
        }
    ]
}
```

I know how to update this after reading each doc and then update them one at a time with forEach. that's not what I want.
I know that updateMany() function accepts aggregate pipelines and in those pipelines you should be able to do something like

```
[
    { $set: { "value1": "$value2"}}
]
```

but since chargeAmount and calculatedChargeAmount is nested inside and array of objects I tried to do this

```
db.collection.updateMany(filter, [
    {
      $set: {
        'services.$[].chargeAmount': '$services.$[].calculatedChargeAmount'
      }
    }
  ]);
```

I get error saying FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Is it not possible to do what I am trying to achieve? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    db.collection.updateMany({"services._id":req.user.id},
                       {$set: {"services.$.chargeAmount" :'services.$.calculatedChargeAmount'}},
                      function (error, success) {
                        if(error)
                        {
                          console.log(error);
                        }
                        else {
 console.log('success');
}
})
```

Remember, here id is the _id for the array services in mongoDB. It must be having one _id automatically got created.

Comment: this does not work either. errro:: "Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."

Comment: Updated the answer! Try to execute that one. Remember the filter matters a lot here while using UpdateMany() function.

Comment: {$set: {"services.$.chargeAmount" :'services.$.calculatedChargeAmount'}}  this does not work if's not in aggregation pipeline. it sets the field with string not value

Comment: @ReshadHasan Do you have an example with Aggregation?